# gstreamer side by side stream

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, gstreamer

i'm currently trying to stream two side by side webcams from my raspberry pi.

i found a pipeline for gstreamer:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! \
video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-640 !\
videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc  ! tcpserversink \
host=192.168.1.108 port=8080 sync=false v4l2src ! videoscale !\
ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 !\
videobox right=-640 ! mix.
```

both webcams indicates that they are active by light, but i only can see the right side.

could someone please help me on this?

regards
carsten

Answer (score 0):

I ran the line fine in my Linux box but just as a wild guess, try adding a `queue` element before every `videomixer` input pad.

Answer (score 0):

I see dev/video1 but no dev/video2 or rather dev/video0 might want to specify that in your v4l2src.

Also I was having trouble with a pipeline similar to yours, this one worked for me:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! videobox border-alpha=0 ! videomixer name=mixme ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=sbs-3d-video.mov v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! videobox left=-320 ! mixme.
```

Sorry for your version of gstreamer:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! videobox border-alpha=0 ! videomixer name=mixme ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=sbs-3d-video.mov v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! videobox left=-320 ! mixme.
```